# Find_java.exe in Android SDK doesn't find Java

Tags: java, android

I've definitely got JDK 1.6.0 installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35`, but it never seems to be able to find it when I try to open the SDK Manager. In task manager, find_java.exe shows up until I stop it (will run for hours).

Are there some environment variables I have to set for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Windows system, use following way to set your `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` Environment variables.

**Windows XP**

- Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select the Advanced tab.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

**Windows Vista:**

- From the desktop, right click the My Computer icon.
- Choose Properties from the context menu.
- Click the Advanced tab (Advanced system settings link in Vista).
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

**Windows 7:**

- From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
- Choose Properties from the context menu.
- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

Now in Addition for the Linux Based System following steps used to set `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` variables,

- Open root folder
- From the View Menu , ticK "Show Hidden Files" , or press Ctrl + H.
- Now you can see a system hidden file called **.bashrc**
- Right click and open it editor, and write following command at the end.

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.6.0_21/bin
  export PATH
  JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_21
  export JAVA_HOME
  NDK_HOME=/opt/android-ndk-r8
  export NDK_HOME
  ```
- Save and Exit.

Comment: Thanks! I tried other ways to edit the environment variables, but this ultimately worked.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are forgetting the `PATH` environmental variable. To check this use,

In Unix/Linux systems,

```
echo $PATH
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

In Windows systems,

```
echo %PATH%
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

If both the tests showed you empty lines, then you may need to set them again.

To set them do this. First try reinstalling java with `UAC` turned off.
If it failed, do this at the `cmd`

```
SetX PATH %PATH%;<path_to_jdk/jre>\bin\
SetX JAVA_HOME <path_to_jdk/jre>
```

Hope it helps and thinking you are using windows.

Comment: In `%PATH%`, there seems to be no Java. `%JAVA_HOME%` is not defined. What should I define it to?

Comment: Added `<path_to_jdk/jre>\bin\` to `%PATH%` and likewise for `%JAVA_HOME%`. It still doesn't work. EDIT: I think I need to reboot to update the path, though, will try that